# How to enlarge geographic map in Python/Plotly choropleth plot?

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-dash, figure, plotly-python

I am making a choropleth plot with Plotly. But, the geographic map looking to small.

[like that:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5s4kS.png)

My code is here:

```
fig = px.choropleth(df,
                    geojson=geojson,
                    locations="Capitalize",
                    featureidkey="properties.name",
                    color="Scale",
                    hover_name='Capitalize',
                    hover_data=['Quantity'],
                    animation_frame="Period",
                    projection="mercator",)

fig.update_geos(fitbounds="locations", visible=False)
fig.update_layout(title_text = 'Product A',
                  autosize=True,
                  hovermode='closest',
                  title_x = 0.5,
                  margin={"r":0,"t":100,"l":0,"b":0},
                  geo=dict(showframe = False, showcoastlines = False))
```

width and height attributes are not making exactly what i want to do. I want to enlarge only geographic map. How can i do that in plotly?

Comment: I changed the projection equirectangular instead of mercator. Then the geographic map enlarged a little bit.

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem. I found this [related issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42722495/plotly-js-choropleth-map-size), which says:

> Plotly tries to take all the available space without changing the
> image ratio. If you have a very wide div there will be a lot of empty
> space to left and right due but it will be filled from the top to the
> bottom.

I increased the `height` of my layout. I went from this:

```
fig.update_layout(margin=dict(l=0, r=0, b=0, t=0),
                  width=1500)
```

to this:

```
fig.update_layout(margin=dict(l=0, r=0, b=0, t=0),
                  width=1500, 
                  height=800)
```

which improved my image size dramatically.

This still left considerable whitespace around my map. I improved this by computing the bounding box instead of using `fitbounds`. I used a helper module `turfpy` to compute the bounding box of a geometry, installed using `pip install turfpy`.

```
from turfpy.measurement import bbox
from functools import reduce

def compute_bbox(gj):
    gj_bbox_list = list(
        map(lambda f: bbox(f['geometry']), gj['features']))
    gj_bbox = reduce(
        lambda b1, b2: [min(b1[0], b2[0]), min(b1[1], b2[1]),
                        max(b1[2], b2[2]), max(b1[3], b2[3])],
        gj_bbox_list)
    return gj_bbox

gj_bbox = compute_bbox(gj)

fig = px.choropleth(fdf,
                    geojson=gj,
                    locations=locationcol,
                    color=datacol,
                    color_continuous_scale="Viridis",
                    range_color=(0, max_value),
                    featureidkey=key,
                    scope='europe',
                    hover_data=[namecol, 'LAD11NM']
                    )
fig.update_geos(
    # fitbounds="locations",
    center_lon=(gj_bbox[0]+gj_bbox[2])/2.0,
    center_lat=(gj_bbox[1]+gj_bbox[3])/2.0,
    lonaxis_range=[gj_bbox[0], gj_bbox[2]],
    lataxis_range=[gj_bbox[1], gj_bbox[3]],
    visible=False,
)
```

Answer (score -1):

Take a look at [Plotly's website](https://plotly.com/python/reference/layout/geo/#layout-geo-fitbounds) and scroll down to the fitbounds section.

I believe your problem may be the code `fig.update_geos(fitbounds="locations", visible=False)`

where you need to change the section "locations" to something else such as "geojson" or "False".

Hope this works!